# How to add role to person after saying smth

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()
ROLE = 'SPECIAL'
BOT_PREFIX = '/'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message, member):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.name == "Pawlu_il_Fenku":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print(f"{member} was given {role}")


client.run('NzY0MjA1MzA1MjQwMjIzNzQ0.X4C3pw.5RmXn1XswHCTWwOQ5i1v5lH5B6I')
```

when i run it and type something it gives me this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpbay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` event has only 1 argument, which is `message`. You cannot use 2 parameters in this event but you can access every attribute that `member` object has with using `message.author`.

Also, I don't recommend you to use `discord.Client` and `discord.Bot` at the same time. `discord.Bot` can do everything that `discord.Client` does.

```py
ROLE = 'SPECIAL'
BOT_PREFIX = '/'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message, member):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.name == "Pawlu_il_Fenku":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
        print(f"{message.author} was given {role}")


client.run('TOKEN')
```

**NOTE**:

You should change your token if you haven't changed yet.